# Backtrace in nested exceptions

Tags: ruby, exception

I am trying to improve the backtrace of a nested exception. Currently I have this:

```
def upsert(doc)
  get(doc.id) ? update(doc) : insert(doc)
rescue => ex
  raise RepositoryError, "#{ex.class}: #{ex.message}"
end
```

In my **upsert** method I want to wrap any exception into a generic one. This solution works but has an annoying side effect: the backtrace of the real problem is lost (the rescued exception)

I might further fix the problem replacing the backtrace with the one from the inner exception:

```
  raise RepositoryError, "#{ex.class}: #{ex.message}", ex.backtrace
```

This shows the backtrace with the real problem, but excludes the line raising **RepositoryError**. I might use `__FILE__:__LINE__` to extend `ex.backtrace` but the insertion is not trivial because I must find the right position inside the backtrace.

Since this seems such a basic-common need: Is there an easier way to achieve everything I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a Java equivalent of nested exceptions as well.  So far, it appears that [Nesty](https://github.com/skorks/nesty) is the way to go.  [I see that Charles Nutter requested #cause](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8257) to be added to the MRI, and something was, but it doesn't display.

```
class HappyError < StandardError
  include Nesty::NestedError
end


begin
  raise 'foo'
rescue => e
  raise HappyError.new
end
```

Looks simple enough (note this implicitly nests the cause which is accessible via $!)